# Show my position using a marker on android (previous marker still appear when position update)

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay

I tried to show my current position on map using a marker, find my code below.
but if my position is changed (position updated), the previous marker is still appear. 
how to remove previous marker. please help

```
public void UpdateMyPosition (Location location){
String addressString = "No location found";

if (location != null) {
    // Update the map location.
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),(int) (longitude * 1E6));
    mapController.animateTo(geoPoint);

    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red);
    MapsOverlay itemizedoverlay2 = new MapsOverlay(drawable, this);

    List<Overlay> myOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "", "");

    itemizedoverlay2.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
    myOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay2);

    mapView.postInvalidate();

    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
      List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
          sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i));
      }
      addressString = sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
  } else {
    addressString = "No location found";
  }

  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),addressString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
myOverlays.clear();
```

before

```
myOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay2);
```

Comment: Hi NicT, thanks for your answer.
My application have two marker type, if i use .clear() method, it will remove all marker. how to remove spesific marker (just my current location) and redraw the marker if i move to another location.

Comment: You can use myOverlays.remove(int i) to remove one from the list

Comment: how to get index from the list?, i tried give index value is 0  myOverlays.remove(0) but not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll be better to use bundled [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html), in this case drawing and updating will be performed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

An other idea would be to not remove the old marker, but to change its position instead.